# Automated theorem proving with SAT

Tags: automated-theorem-proving

If you had a polynomial time algorithm for determining boolean satisfiability how would you prove/disprove a conjecture like the Reimann-Zeta hypothesis (or the Pythagorean theorem for that matter) from axioms?

Comment: You couldn't.  Those require something stronger than SAT (first-order logic, etc.).

Comment: SAT was recently used on the [Erdos Discrepancy Problem](http://vzn1.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/great-moments-in-empiricalexperimental-mathtcs-research-breakthough-sat-induction-idea/) with some success and its also being used to construct small optimal sorting networks, solving long open problems of Knuth. do think/conjecture that this will expand & there will be more powerful uses of SAT in the future incl induction over infinite values, but so far its barely even a twinkle in anyones eye.

Comment: And even if you could (but see the comment by @D.W.), a "polynomial time algorithm" is not necessarily a practical one at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you believe that a proof or disproof has reasonable length, you could come up with one SAT instance which states *$x_1,\ldots,x_n$ encodes a proof of the Riemann Hypothesis*, and another one stating *$x_1,\ldots,x_n$ encodes a refutation of the Riemann hypothesis*. The formula will have size polynomial in $n$, though probably not linear; if you're careful, maybe quasilinear ($n\log^{O(1)}n$). You can then apply your magic SAT solver to find out which, if any, of these options is correct. Don't hold your breath, though – as mentioned in the comments, it is hard to imagine an algorithm which would be efficient enough to handle the required value of $n$ in a realistic amount of time.

Comment: There is only one Riemann Hypothesis, so its proof is of constant length, so it can be verified in constant time, regardless of the complexity of SAT. And how do I come up with that proof, anyway?